# ArrayList empties out when moving to another class

Tags: java

completely basic java student here. I am having a problem with my project for AP Comp sci in which when I create an object for my cartClass in my MenuClass, I get this very long list of errors(repeats these lines over and over):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at ICSMenuClass.<init>(ICSMenuClass.java:27)
at ICSCartClass.<init>(ICSCartClass.java:20)
```

Now my other concern is the fact that when I add elements to my item and itemprice ArrayLists, they arnt stored in the ArrayList when I go to my cart class(The code is VERY messy, also im only adding items to the 'item' and 'itemprice' ArrayLists):

```
import java.util.*;
public class ICSMenuClass extends Objclass{

//  public static void main(String[] args)
//  {
//      
//      ICSMenuClass i1 = new ICSMenuClass();
//      System.out.println(i1);
//  }

ArrayList<String> ItemName = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Double> ItemPrice = new ArrayList<Double>();
public ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<Double> itemprice = new ArrayList<Double>();
ICSCartClass icsc2 = new ICSCartClass();
ICSMenuClass icsm2 = new ICSMenuClass();

//public ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
//public ArrayList<Double> itemprice = new ArrayList<Double>();
//public ICSCartClass icsc1 = new ICSCartClass();

public Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public ICSMenuClass()
{

    //super(item, itemprice);
    //item.add("Lemon");
//      this.item = item;
//      this.ItemPrice = ItemPrice;
    iteminfo();
}






public void iteminfo()
{


    String user = "admin";  
    String uselessfiller = "null";
    String addItem = "addItem";
    String removeItem = "removeItem";
    String changePrice =  "changePrice";
    String gocart1 = "GoCart";



    //final ArrayList<String> combined = new ArrayList<String>();

    //item.addAll(itemprice);


    System.out.println("Who is this?");
    String userused = scan.nextLine();
    String viewInventory = "SeeInventory";

    if(userused.equalsIgnoreCase(user))
    {
        int j = 1;
        while(j < 2)
        {
        System.out.println("Would you like to edit an item? y/n");
        String answer;
        String yes1 = "y";

        answer = scan.nextLine();

        if(answer.equals(yes1))

            System.out.println("What would you like to do?  (Type: addItem, removeitem, changePrice, SeeInventory, GoCart)");
            //scan.nextLine();
            String ans1 = scan.nextLine();


                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Add Item
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if(ans1.equals(addItem))
                {
                    AddItemtoInventory();

                }else{





                //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Remove Items
                //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                if(ans1.equals(removeItem))
                {
                 RemoveItemfromInventory();

                }else{
                //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Change Price
                //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


                if(ans1.equals(changePrice))
                {
                    ChangePriceofItem();

                }else{
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //View Inventory
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


                if(ans1.equals(viewInventory))
                {
                    CheckInventory();
                }else{


                if(ans1.equals(gocart1)){

                    this.item = ItemName;
                    this.itemprice = ItemPrice;
                    icsm2.GotoCart();
                }else{

                if(ans1 == "n"){
                            //AccountLogin acctlogn1 = new AccountLogin();
                            //System.out.println(acctlogn1);
                            System.out.println("Ok");
                        }
                    }

                }   }}}}}   

}



//Adding item to inventory





public void AddItemtoInventory()
{
    System.out.println("Ok, how many items would you like to add?");
    int i = 1;
    int desireditemnumb1 = scan.nextInt();

    while (i <= desireditemnumb1)
    {

        String filler1 = "null";
        String useless1 = scan.nextLine();
        useless1 = filler1;
        System.out.println("Ok, enter item #" + i + " and the ISBN number   after it.");



        String itemname = scan.nextLine();
        item.add(itemname);


        System.out.println("Please add a price to the item: ");
        Double itemprice1 = scan.nextDouble();
        itemprice.add(itemprice1);

//          System.out.println("Please set the amount of the item to add to the inventory: ");
//          int i2 = scan.nextInt();
//          for(int j = 0; j < i2; j++)
//          {
//          invAmount.add(itemname);
//          }


        System.out.println("Added " + itemname + " to inventory");
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("would you like to see your inventory?");
    scan.nextLine();
    String seeinventory1 = scan.nextLine();

    if(seeinventory1.equals("y"))
    {
        System.out.println(item + "\n" + itemprice);


    }else{
        System.out.println("Ok...");


    }
}



//Removing item method

public void RemoveItemfromInventory()
{

    System.out.println("Ok, how many items would you like to remove?");



    int i = 1;
    int desireditemnumb1 = scan.nextInt();

    while(i <= desireditemnumb1)
    {
            System.out.println("Ok, type the number which the item is allocated");
            System.out.println(item);
            int index1 = scan.nextInt();
            item.remove(index1);
            itemprice.remove(index1);

            System.out.println("Removed " + item.get(index1) + " from inventory");
            i++;
    }


    String yes1 = "y";
    System.out.println("Would you like to see your inventory?");
    String yes2 = scan.nextLine();



    if(yes2.equals(yes1))

    System.out.println(item + "\n" + itemprice);
}





public void ChangePriceofItem()
{

    System.out.println("Ok, type the number which the item is allocated");
    System.out.println(item);

    int index1 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Ok, now choose the price the item will cost");
    double itemprice1 = scan.nextDouble();
    itemprice.set(index1, itemprice1);
    System.out.println("Changed price of " + item.get(index1) + " within inventory");

}





public void CheckInventory()
{

    System.out.println(item + "\n" + itemprice + "\n" + invAmount);
    double sum = 0;

    for (double i : itemprice)
        sum += i;
    System.out.println("The value of the inventory: " + "$" + sum);
}



public void GotoCart()
{

    System.out.println(icsc2);
}
}
```

And my cart class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ICSCartClass extends ICSMenuClass{

public Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public ArrayList<Double> ItemPrice1 = new ArrayList<Double>();


//  public static void main(String[] args)
//  {
//      
//      
//      ICSCartClass c1 = new ICSCartClass();
//      System.out.println(c1);
//  }




public ICSCartClass()
{
    //super(item, itemprice);
    addItemDefaults();
}



public void addItemDefaults()
{


    ItemName.addAll(item);
    ItemPrice.addAll(itemprice);

    WhatDoCart();
}


public void WhatDoCart()
{


    System.out.println("What do you want to do with the cart? ");

    System.out.println("Plese choose the number that shows what you want to do: ");
    System.out.println("Add an item = 1" + "\t\t" + "Remove an item = 2" + "\t" + "Exchange an item = 3" + "\t" + "Checkout cart = 4");

    int cartans1 = scan.nextInt();

    if(cartans1 == 1)
        AddItemstoCart();

    if(cartans1 == 2)
        RemoveItemsfromCart();

    if(cartans1 == 3)
        ExcangeItemsinCart();

    if(cartans1 == 4)
        CheckoutCartNow();






}

public void AddItemstoCart()
{

    int i = -1;

    while(i < cart.size())
    {



        System.out.println("What item do you want to add? Press 9 to checkout.");
        System.out.println(ItemName  + "\n" + ItemPrice1);
        int ItemAns1 = scan.nextInt();

        if(ItemAns1 == 9)
        {
            WhatDoCart();
        }else{

        String Itemname2 = item.get(ItemAns1);
        int index1 = item.indexOf(ItemAns1);
        double getprice = itemprice.indexOf(index1);
        cartPrice.add(getprice);

        cart.add(Itemname2);

        System.out.println(cart);
        i++;
        }

    }   



}



public void RemoveItemsfromCart()
{

    int i = -1;

    while(i < cart.size())
    {



        System.out.println("What item do you want to remove (You must have at least 2 items for checkout)? Press 9 to checkout.");
        System.out.println(cart);
        int ItemAns1 = scan.nextInt();

        if(ItemAns1 == 9)
        {
            WhatDoCart();
        }else{

        String Itemname2 = cart.get(ItemAns1);
        cart.remove(Itemname2);
        int index1 = cartPrice.indexOf(ItemAns1); 
        cartPrice.remove(index1);
        System.out.println(cart);
        i++;
        }

    }   





}





public void ExcangeItemsinCart()
{


    int i = -1;

    while(i < cart.size())
    {



        System.out.println("What item do you want to exchange? Press 9 to checkout.");
        System.out.println(ItemName);
        int ItemAns1 = scan.nextInt();

        if(ItemAns1 == 9)
        {
            WhatDoCart();
        }else{

        String Itemname2 = ItemName.get(ItemAns1);
        cart.set(ItemAns1, Itemname2);
        System.out.println(cart);
        i++;
        }

    }   




}





public void CheckoutCartNow()
{
    System.out.println("    Do you want to check out the cart now? y/n");
    scan.nextLine();
    String Ans1 = scan.nextLine();


    if(Ans1 == "y")
    {
        CarttoString();
    }else{
        if(Ans1 == "n")
        {
            WhatDoCart();
        }

        }
}





public void CarttoString()
{
    cart.clear();

    //ItemAmount.add(ItemPrice);



}

}
```

Another error I have is when I want to got to the cart class, it takes me back to the beginning of the itemInfo() method, and I have to type anything but "Admin" in there to go to the cartClass.

Thank you for you help, and sorry about the long code, i'm not good at cropping what I need. Also, I want to know how to get my item/itemprice ArrayLists keep their elements when I go to the cart class. Thank you!

---

Ok, so I've done some fixes to it, but it still goes back to asking: "Who is this?" after I type GoCart. Plus the array still shows up empty.

```
public void iteminfo()
{


    String user = "admin";  

//      String addItem = "addItem";
//      String removeItem = "removeItem";
//      String changePrice =  "changePrice";
//      String gocart1 = "GoCart";



    //final ArrayList<String> combined = new ArrayList<String>();

    //item.addAll(itemprice);


    System.out.println("Who is this?");
    String userused = scan.nextLine();
    String viewInventory = "SeeInventory";

    if(userused.equalsIgnoreCase(user))
    {
        int j = 1;
        while(j < 2)
        {
        System.out.println("Would you like to edit an item? y/n");
        String answer;
        //String yes1 = "y";

        answer = scan.nextLine();

        if(answer.equals("y"))

            System.out.println("What would you like to do?  (Type: addItem, removeitem, changePrice, SeeInventory, GoCart)");
            //scan.nextLine();
            String ans1 = scan.nextLine();


                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Add Item
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if(ans1.equals("addItem"))
                {
                    AddItemtoInventory();

                }else{





                //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Remove Items
                //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                if(ans1.equals("removeItem"))
                {
                 RemoveItemfromInventory();

                }else{
                //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Change Price
                //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


                if(ans1.equals("changePrice"))
                {
                    ChangePriceofItem();

                }else{
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //View Inventory
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


                if(ans1.equals("SeeInventory"))
                {
                    CheckInventory();
                }else{


                if(ans1.equals("GoCart")){
                    j++;
                    this.item = ItemName;
                    this.itemprice = ItemPrice;
                    GotoCart();
                }else{

                if(ans1 == "n"){
                            //AccountLogin acctlogn1 = new AccountLogin();
                            //System.out.println(acctlogn1);
                            System.out.println("Ok");
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    }   
                    }
                    }
                    }

                }
        }   

}
```

Comment: remove the empty lines in your code could make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are initializing your J in the `iteminfo()` method ICSMenuClass. You are not decrementing it in your function any where. Which means that your loop would never end `while(j < 2)` would always be true.

There are many useless variables declared which makes it hard to understand the flow, e.g.

```
String yes1 = "y";
```

You can do `if(answer.equals("y"))` to avoid the extra variable being declared.

Comment: Your item and itemprice variables are only global to the ICSMenuClass. If you want to access them to other classes. You will have to pass it to the constructor when declaring the objects. Otherwise you won't get values in other classes

Comment: Also there is so much code to look at. I think it has got lot of errors

String filler1 = "null";
String useless1 = scan.nextLine();
useless1 = filler1;

These line of code are sort of useless really. You are inputting something from UI and than replacing it with "null" string. It is useless to read something and than replace it

Comment: yea, I know that i have way way way too much code on them, but I wanted to know where my errors were and see if there were anymore errors in there. also how do I do the previous action? I don't know how to make it global to the other classes. Also thanks for you help so far.